# How do I reset sculpting tools to default? Each click destroys the mesh

Tags: sculpting

I was following a tutorial. When I got to the Sculpting Tab, every time I tried to sculpt, each click would devastate the mesh.

The sculpting tools were fine yesterday. Really don't know what I've done to ruin it.

This is what happens with one click on the model's face...

[image]

Comment: It seems you have Dyntopo enabled? Try without or with a finer resolution?

Answer (score 3):

In the *Tool* panel > *Brushes*, click on the down arrow button and *Reset Brush*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the Reset brush popup can also be found in the `active tool and workspace` panel.
[image]