# How can I reset a tool to its defaults?

Tags: edit-mode, tools

Each tool has various settings associated with it. For example the [Inset Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/inset_faces.html) tool has the following in Blender 3.0:

[image: The inset faces options in blender]

When following a tutorial, the teacher does not always show the tool settings they're using. If I can assume that they are using the default settings, how can I make sure my tool settings match? Can I reset the tool somehow? Can I look up the defaults somewhere so I can reset it myself?

[Sculpting tools](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199197/how-do-i-reset-sculpting-tools-to-default-each-click-destroys-the-mesh) can be reset, but what about others?

Comment: For most tools, if you right click on one of the tools input fields, the popup menu should show "Reset All to Default" as an option.  It varies how well this works.

Comment: Thanks @MartyFouts that does seem to work (at least for my Inset Faces example)! Would you like to provide that as an answer?

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  I added it as an swer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most tools, if you right click on one of the tools input fields, the popup menu should show "Reset All to Default" as an option. It varies how well this works.

In the worst case you can reset everything by selecting *Load Factor Settings* from the *Defaults* submenu of the *File* menu.

Comment: Worth noting, that some tools have this but some tools can only reset themselves one setting at a time. Easy enough to right click each input and reset it individually though.

Answer (score 0):

Some values reset to default when you hover over them & hit the Backspace button.

A few tools however are set to zero when you do that, regardless of the default value (I forget which ones). Still, I find the Backspace button very useful for resetting values.